# Problem with passing Params between Stack and Drawer Navigator screens - React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Hi I am new to react native and trying to learn few things. I am trying to pass a data from one screen to another.

I need to pass the video id to Web View on another page to play YouTube video. but the Video Id is not passed to another screen.

I've tried to pass Param to one screen to another.In this project, I am using stack and drawer navigators.

The param id is "ytId"

also i tried to pass the param with AsyncStorage. Please anyone assist me with this issue and thanks in advance.

## Screen 3:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import { Button, Icon } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  navOptions

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

    navOptions = navigation;
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;

    return {
      headerLeft: (
        <Button
          transparent
          onPress={() => params._onHeaderEventControl()}
        >
          <Icon
            name="menu"
            style={{ fontSize: 30, color: 'white' }}
          />
        </Button>
      )
    }
  }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { listLoaded: false };
  }
  onHeaderEventControl() {
    const { params = {} } = navOptions.state;
    params._openNav()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      _onHeaderEventControl: this.onHeaderEventControl,
      _openNav: () => this.openDrawer()
    })

    return fetch(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=lcwell&type=video&key=AIzaSyCwCHIfFvkMZ1aR6eIvy4sUIgqV6hIZ3qU')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          listLoaded: true,
          videoList: Array.from(responseJson.items)
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  openDrawer() {
    this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
  }
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.listLoaded && (
          <View style={{ paddingTop: 0 }}>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.videoList}
              renderItem={({ item }) =>
                <TubeItem
                  navigate={navigate}
                  id={item.id.videoId}
                  title={item.snippet.title}
                  imageSrc={item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}
                />

              }
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />

          </View>

        )}
        {!this.state.listLoaded && (
          <View style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
            <Text>LOADING</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export class TubeItem extends React.Component {

onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigate('Screen5', { ytId: this.props.id })
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onPress}>
        <View style={{ paddingTop: 20, alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Image
            style={{ width: '100%', height: 200 }}
            source={{ uri: this.props.imageSrc }}
          />
          <Text>
            {this.props.title}
          </Text>
        </View>

      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

## Screen 5:

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class VideoDetail extends React.Component {
  navOptions

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {

    navOptions = navigation;
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
  }
  onHeaderEventControl() {
    const { params = {} } = navOptions.state;
    params._openNav()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      _onHeaderEventControl: this.onHeaderEventControl,
      _openNav: () => this.openDrawer()
    })
  }
  render() {

    let tubeId = this.props.navigation.getParam('ytId', 'NO VIDEO');
    let tubeUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${tubeId}`;
    return (
      <WebView
        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{ uri: tubeUrl }}
      />

    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a state container like redux.
It allows you to pass variable and parameters from a component to another.
I didn't explain all in details, others do it better than me and there a re a lot of tutorials to implement redux. 
You can find the official redux website https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Main steps would be:

1. Import redux in your `package.json`
2. Create a store with `createStore` method from imported package
3. Surround your main view with new created object `<Provider store={store}>`
4. Declare needed methods in your store
5. Connect **Screen 3** & **Screen 5** to redux

You will then be able to pass variable between your screens and access it very easy via `props` property.

It will simplify your life!

Otherwise we would need the way you declare your Stack and Drawer to be able to answer :-)